# How to properly run GUI VNC clients on Cygwin

Tags: windows-10, cygwin, vnc, vnc-viewer, remmina

I want to use vinagre or remmina VNC clients but they fail to run:

```
$ vinagre
C:/cygwin64/bin/vinagre.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygvte-2.91-0.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

$ remmina
C:/cygwin64/bin/remmina.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygvte-2.91-0.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I can't find anything on `cygvte`, I installed `vte` using `apt-cyg` but that didn't fix the issue.

How to acquire the required resource?

**Update!** I followed DavidPostill's answer, but it turned into a Dominoes! I kept resolving the dependencies and it kept asking for more, I installed these:

```
libvte2.91_0 libtelepathy-glib0 libspice-client-gtk3.0_5 libspice-client-glib2.0_8 libsecret1_0 libgtk-vnc2.0_0 libfreerdp1.2  libdbus-glib_1_2 libavahi-ui-gtk3_0 libavahi-gobject0 libavahi-common3
```

Now it came to the point where the error doesn't even indicate what's missing:

```
$ vinagre
C:/cygwin64/bin/vinagre.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I continued with Remmina:

```
$ remmina
C:/cygwin64/bin/remmina.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygssh_threads-4.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I installed `libssh4` but it doesn't resolve the dependency, it throws the same error above.

Answer (score 1):

#### I can't find anything on cygvte

You need the `GTK+ terminal emulator widget` package.

---

#### How can I find out which package `GTK+ terminal emulator widget` is in?

The easiest way to find the package containing a particular command or file is to use the [Cygwin Package Search](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi) page:

1. Open the [Cygwin Package Search](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi) web page in your web browser.

   > [image]
2. Enter the name of the program you are looking for (`cygvte-2.91-0.dll`).
3. Press "Go" on the web page.

   > [image]
4. Click on [libvte2.91_0-0.50.2-1](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Flibvte2.91_0%2Flibvte2.91_0-0.50.2-1&grep=cygvte-2.91-0.dll)  as this is the most likely match.

   > [image]

   This confirms that the `GTK+ terminal emulator widget` is the correct package to install to resolve your missing file issue.

Comment: Hello I installed libvte2.91_0 as well as libvte-devel and even more but the issue still persists, please see the updated question, thanks a lot.

Comment: https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=cygssh_threads-4.dll